# JIRA - REST API - gadget data

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to use JIRA REST API to query issues. I was able to successfully fetch the issues. I am not the admin of JIRA.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to 'group by' the results? (I can write some custom function if it is not available in API)
2. Is there any way to get the gadget data as well using API? (I want the chart img in binary format or something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:
1.) no it is not possible to group the result set
2.) no it is not possible to get gadget data over Rest

Answer (score 0):

1) You can do it in JavaScript or any other language.

2) Again, you can do it in JavaScript or any other language. There are plenty JavaScript plugins: http://www.chartjs.org/.

Do you use any programming language to run JIRA REST requests?